# Adding a label to filer log entries in Loki

Tags: python, label, grafana, fluent-bit, grafana-loki

I have created simple script to test Grafana Loki. It sends messages over Fluentbit:

```
from fluent import sender


messages = [
    {'from': 'userA', 'to': 'userB', 'log': 'Hello!'},
    {'from': 'userB', 'to': 'userA', 'log': 'Hi!'},
]
for message in messages:
    logger = sender.FluentSender('app', host='foo', port=24224)
    result = logger.emit('app.messages', message)
    if result:
        print('Message sent: {}'.format(message))
```

**Fluent-bit config:**

```
[INPUT]
    Name        forward
    Listen      0.0.0.0
    Port        24224
[Output]
    Name loki
    Match *
    Url ${LOKI_URL}
    RemoveKeys source
    Labels {job="remote-log"}
    LabelKeys container_name
    BatchWait 1
    BatchSize 1001024
    LineFormat json
    LogLevel info
```

And I get the message in Grafana:

[image]

Grafana is showing `no unique labels`. How do I set unique label and in general how do I add them? I thought it can be done once message is sent as the first parameter of `logger.emit` is label, but it is missing in Grafana. I might extend my Fluent Bit configuration to do a filtering... But setting labels in an App level would be cool

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you resolved this but the function `json` should allow for interpretation of log events in JSON formatting them as key value outputs.

```
{hostname=~'.+'} 
| json
```

Unfortunately (this got me too), the `json` function in LogQL is strictly RFC compliant therefore JSON elements that are strings must be quoted with `"`. ([RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159))

Below is an example of this with single (`'`) vs. double (`"`) quotes. As you can see the single quotes are not interpreted however the double quotes are.

[image]